# std mpsc sender channel closed when used in closure

Tags: multithreading, rust, closures

I'm trying to create a thread watching for file changes in rust. I'm using the [notify](https://docs.rs/notify/latest/notify/) crate to get file change events.

The following code shows what is run in the watch thread:

```rust
use std::{path::PathBuf, thread};

use log::{error, info};
use notify::Watcher;

fn main() {
    env_logger::init();

    let (tx, rx) = std::sync::mpsc::channel();

    thread::spawn({
        let config_path = PathBuf::from("config.toml");

        move || {
            let mut watcher =
                notify::recommended_watcher(move |res: Result<notify::Event, notify::Error>| {
                    match res {
                        Ok(event) => match event.kind {
                            notify::event::EventKind::Modify(notify::event::ModifyKind::Data(
                                notify::event::DataChange::Any,
                            )) => {
                                info!("Reloading config file");
                                tx.send(true).ok();
                            }
                            _ => (),
                        },
                        Err(e) => {
                            error!("Notify Error: {}", e);
                        }
                    }
                })
                .unwrap();
            watcher.watch(&config_path, notify::RecursiveMode::NonRecursive)
        }
    });

    loop {
        match rx.recv() {
            Ok(_) => {
                // reload config
            }
            Err(e) => {
                error!("Error while watching config file: {}", e);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```ini
# Cargo.toml

[dependencies]
env_logger = "0.10.0"
log = "0.4.19"
notify = "6.0.1"
```

The problem is that I get the output `Error while watching config file: receiving on a closed channel` when trying to receive from the channel.

I expected that the sender `tx` is moved into the closure without the channel being closed. But somehow it gets closed.

I already looked through [known problems](https://docs.rs/notify/latest/notify/#known-problems) of the notify crate, but I think nothing relates to my problem.

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`watch()`](https://docs.rs/notify/latest/notify/trait.Watcher.html#tymethod.watch) is non-blocking. From the documentation (emphasis mine):

> **Begin** watching a new path.

So it is fire-and-forget. You don't need to spawn a new thread for it. And in fact, when you do, the thread terminates immediately after the `watch`, the watcher is dropped and the channel is closed.

Here's what you should do:

```rust
fn main() {
    let (tx, rx) = std::sync::mpsc::channel();

    let config_path = PathBuf::from("config.toml");

    let mut watcher =
        notify::recommended_watcher(move |res: Result<notify::Event, notify::Error>| match res {
            Ok(event) => match event.kind {
                notify::event::EventKind::Modify(notify::event::ModifyKind::Data(
                    notify::event::DataChange::Any,
                )) => {
                    info!("Reloading config file");
                    tx.send(true).ok();
                }
                _ => (),
            },
            Err(e) => {
                error!("Notify Error: {}", e);
            }
        })
        .unwrap();
    watcher.watch(&config_path, notify::RecursiveMode::NonRecursive);

    loop {
        match rx.recv() {
            Ok(_) => {
                // reload config
            }
            Err(e) => {
                error!("Error while watching config file: {}", e);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```